# How I can plot the below map?

Tags: plotting, difference-equations, iterators

I have tried to plot the following map:

$\qquad
\begin{cases}
y_{n+1}=r y_n^{x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}}\\
y_1=x_1-x_2 \quad 
\end{cases}$

using the code shown below. The error I have got is that

> x[1] - x[2] can't be used as an iterator

However, it works if I try it analytically then how I can got its plot?

```
funcs = 
  RecurrenceTable[
    {y[n + 1] == r( y[n]^(x[n+1] - x[n+2])), 
     y[1] == x[1] - x[2]}, 
    y, {n, 1, 5}];
Plot[funcs /. r -> 1, {x[1] - x[2], 0, 1}, 
  Evaluated -> True,   PlotRange -> All]
```

**Note** This is just explantion about running of the below code , The below Code seems converge always to `r` for odd iteration and even iteration  but the sequence I mean is diverge such that it take two distincts limit according the parity of iteration odd and even , As example of the above system we may take this example: $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$ here we have limit of a_n for n odd close to `0.56778606544394002098000796382530333102219963214866` and for even iteration we have `0.85885772008416606762434379473241623070938618180813` for more behavior of this sequence one can check the link of [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716498/156150) in SE .Probably I'm wrong in the reformulation of the above general recursive sequence.

Comment: You need another equation to generate the values for `x[n+1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow the sequence `x[1], ..., x[6]` must be defined. This can be done by giving each of the six values), giving a recursive formula or by defining function `x` over the domain [1, ..., 6]. I will use the last method to show you how a plot can be made.

```
x[n_] := Log2[1/(n + 1)]
Module[{r, yVals},
  r = 1;
  yVals =
    RecurrenceTable[
      {y[n + 1] == r (y[n]^(x[n + 1] - x[n + 2])), y[1] == x[1] - x[2]},
      y, {n, 1, 5}];
 ListPlot[yVals]]
```

[image: plot]